# Unknown error while creating client using Keycloak REST API

Tags: api, keycloak

I'm trying to create a new client in my springboot realm through the keycloak REST API using postman, but I'm getting an unknown error as the response.

The URL in post method is

```
localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/springboot/clients
```

The header includes

```
content-type - application/json
authorization - bearer <access token...>
```

The json body is

```
{    
  "id":"1",
  "clientId":"zzzzz",
  "name":"aaaaa",
  "description":"bbbbb",
  "redirectUris":[ "\\" ],
  "enabled":"true"
}
```

The response I'm getting is `403 : unknown error`.

Comment: 403 no permissions, but you are authorized. most probably add roles to your user, something from realm-management, like create/manage-clients. should work if you try with admin user access token

Comment: i am new to keycloak , i have set role for my user and i have also set client role too but still not working .... should i do client registration?

Comment: as far as I remember, create user under 'master' realm, assign roles from 'Realm management' something like 'create client' or 'manage client'  (not sure about wording). what I am trying to say, user with permissions to create clients should be created under main 'master' realm. you can assign 'admin' role to make your code passing, and slowly play with roles to find right one, or read documentation

Comment: i have successfully created a client through api using intial access token from client registration in realm settings . But now my doubt is how can i get the intial access token  from client registration through api. In the above case i got that registration intial access token through their front end admin console. Now i want to do the same through api call. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 15):

I obtained the same error because the client had not the necessary role.

- Go to Clients -> {your-client-name}
- Select the 'Service Account Roles' tab
- Add the necessary role. (In my case I needed the admin role)

[image]

Comment: Adding the 'admin' role to service accounts under the 'admin-cli' client fixed it for me.