# Keycloak view-users, manage-users and admin roles not found in Services Account Roles

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I'm trying to define **Services Account Roles** in Keycloak to list users via the REST API.

But `manage-users`, `view-users` and `admin` not found.

[image]

It's necessary this permission roles to resolve this error (unknown_error), according to:

[Keycloak Admin Rest API unknown_error for update user API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60359979/keycloak-admin-rest-api-unknown-error-for-update-user-api)

[Unknown error while creating client using Keycloak REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58953433/unknown-error-while-creating-client-using-keycloak-rest-api)

This is the url called and error shown:

[image]

What would be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Those are `realm-management` client roles:
[image]

Comment: I have three realms: master, prod and dev. Note of them I found `realm-management` client option to field Client Roles.

Answer (score 0):

jan-garaj response is correct but to elaborate a little based on similar questions from many users.

- The client role selection box only shows a couple clients.  It does not show all the clients.  So you need to type in the first few characters of "realm" to see the selection get updated with the option you are looking for.